# Cannot access public IPv6 address from outside

Tags: linux, ipv6

My pc is assigned 3 global scope IPv6 addresses (1 is local) which are

```
inet6 2402:d000:a000:8090:b0e5:ed66:90e2:2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 fe80::eff8:de37:10c7:db4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
inet6 2402:d000:a000:8090:e50d:59d8:1b88:657c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 2402:d000:a000:8090:9141:cda:42b4:3269
```

.
When I access internet I can see my public ip address as `2402:d000:a000:8090:e50d:59d8:1b88:657c` this. Those addresses are **not** based on MAC. However I cant `ping` or `traceroute` or access those addresses from outside my network. Does privacy extension avoid accessing those addresses form outside? What is the reason for that?

Here is my firewall status:

```
lakinduakash@ultimatex:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ufw status returns inactive.

Comment: Are you running a firewall or stateful filter that is blocking incoming connections?

Comment: @Zoredache I have the updated question

Comment: So what is between your "PC" and the Internet connection?

Comment: @MichaelHampton wireless router which have 4g conection

Comment: That's too vague. You need to be specific.

Comment: @MichaelHampton well. I have wifi router and It was previously assigned private ipv4 address in ISP's network. I recently requested public ip and now I have ipv6 addresses above. When I lookup my ip from internet It shows the one of above ip address. Does privacy extension in IPv6 have effect on this scenario?

Comment: What model of router is it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Huawei B310s-925

Comment: Hmm. Did you check its firewall? That's most likely where the problem is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think router have no such firewall. It might be problem with ISP and I will contact them. Thanks